# How to have analysis service up and running in SQL Server Express Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, analysis

I am badly stuck up with this problem!

I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and Business Intelligence Development Studio.

I am assigned a Analysis Project.

Now it so happens that I have an express edition and I know that Express edition does not have analysis services included in it.

So my question is **How do I use Analysis services?**

I have spent 2 days of my life searching for the downloads of analysis services. Can anyone do the trick for me?

Comment: You will probably need SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition. It's $49 direct http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/productID.221634300 or $44 from buy.com http://www.buy.com/prod/microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-developer-edition-complete-product-1-user/215778376.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL Server Analysis Services is available only in Standard Edition, Enterprise Edition and Datacenter Edition. See [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#SSAS). You will need to *buy* such an product. Evaluation versions are available but you cannot deploy them in production. Developer edition is also available for you to *develop* the solution, but in production you need to deploy a correctly licensed Standard or Enterprise edition.