# Cannot find SQL Server Analysis Services in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I use SQL Server 2012 Express and SQL Server 2012 Management Studio (I don't know if both are necessary, I saw that in a tutorial) and I want to add the feature Analysis Services. I ran the Setup.exe and in "feature selection" the option Management Tools - Basic was selected. 
I tried to connect to Analysis Services like this:

```
SQL Server Management Studio -> File menu -> Connect Object Explorer -> Server type
```

where it is supposed to be the option Analysis Services but there is the default and unique option "Database Engine".

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you installed the sql analysis services ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have analysis service up and running in SQL Server Express Edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587981/how-to-have-analysis-service-up-and-running-in-sql-server-express-edition)

Comment: @AbdulHannanIjaz I installed this: [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41658)

Comment: Read the system requirement also. as it will solve your problem. You also need sql server analysis server ... which mean you have to install sql server standard edition atleast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this completely with all features or atleast features related to analysis services [Download Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=29066)

Comment: One more question, I read that I can move a database from a server to another via Copy Database Wizard. But Copy Database Wizard is not available in the Express edition. This means that I cannot move my database from Express edition to the server downloaded from your link above?

Comment: Take backup of your database and then on new server use restore wizard to restore your database.